# Parsley field validation event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsley.js

I'm currently trying out Parsley.js, it works pretty good if you ask me however I have a few questions:

1. What event should I listen to in order to append a glyphicon to the input's parent as soon as the `input` gets the class `parsley-success` or `parsley-error` class? The `field:success` and `field-error` [events](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-events-overview) won't get fired without `validate()`.

I tried this for example:

```
$('.form-control').on('field:success', function () {
    if ($(this).parent().find('i').length) { //remove favicon if one's present
        $(this).parent().find('i').remove();
    }
    $(this).parent().append('<i class="fa fa-check-circle fa-lg fa-fw"></i>');
});
```

but nothing happens when the `input` get's an error class assigned

2. Im working with Ninja Forms in my Wordpress install, how would you guys [assign the attributes](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#validators) to the inputs? This is not possible within the ui in the backend of NF. Currently I'm adding them with Javascript after the page has loaded but I wonder if this is the best way.

Comment: Anybody with knowledge about this subject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems my lack of Javascript was killing me with this question. After a lot of trying and debugging I got it to work exactly the way I wanted.
Instead of using `$('.form-control')` to listen to, I needed `window.Parsley` to listen to. so my function is the following now:

```
//field success
window.Parsley.on('field:success', function() {
    var field = this.$element[0].id;
    // This global callback will be called for any field that fails validation.
    console.log('Validation succeeded for: ', field);
    $('#' + field).parent().append('<i class="fa fa-check-circle fa-lg fa-fw"></i>');
});
```

this works flawlessly and add the glyph when the field is successfully validated.

Don't forget to add the attributes to the field itself, otherwise it does not know what to validate against.
I add the attributes with javascript. In the NinjaForms backend I add a class to the `input` (I can't add attributes from there). After that I use this class as the selector and add the attributes, very easy:

```
var textonly = $('input.ninja-forms-field.text-only-input');//the class is 'text-only-input'
if( textonly.length ) {
    textonly.attr('data-parsley-trigger','focusout');
    textonly.attr('data-parsley-trigger-after-failure','keyup');
    textonly.attr('data-parsley-pattern', '^[a-z A-Z]+$');
    textonly.attr('data-parsley-pattern-message', 'Dit veld mag alleen maar letters en spaties bevatten. Minimaal 2 letters');
    textonly.attr('minlength','2');
}
```

You can find my example on the following url's:

http://boriskamp.nl/contact/

http://boriskamp.nl/webdesign/

Here's my complete code to get it to work:

```
//make jQuery reference to $
```

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
'use strict';

```
// change input types:

var checkbox = $('#ninja_forms_field_15_options_span input.ninja-forms-field.checkbox-input');
if( checkbox.length ) {
    checkbox.attr('data-parsley-trigger','click');
    checkbox.attr('data-parsley-trigger-after-failure','click');
    checkbox.attr('data-parsley-multiple','betreft');
    checkbox.attr('data-parsley-mincheck','1');
}
var textonly = $('input.ninja-forms-field.text-only-input');
if( textonly.length ) {
    textonly.attr('data-parsley-trigger','focusout');
    textonly.attr('data-parsley-trigger-after-failure','keyup');
    textonly.attr('data-parsley-pattern', '^[a-z A-Z]+$');
    textonly.attr('data-parsley-pattern-message', 'Dit veld mag alleen maar letters en spaties bevatten. Minimaal 2 letters');
    textonly.attr('minlength','2');
}
var email = $('input.ninja-forms-field.email-input');
if( email.length ) {
    email.get(0).type = 'email';
    email.attr('required','');
    email.attr('data-parsley-trigger','focusout');
    email.attr('data-parsley-trigger-after-failure','keyup');
}
var tel = $('input.ninja-forms-field.telefoon-input');
if( tel.length ) {
    tel.get(0).type = 'tel';
    tel.attr('data-parsley-trigger','focusout');
    tel.attr('data-parsley-trigger-after-failure','keyup');
    tel.attr('data-parsley-type','digits');
}
var bericht = $('textarea.ninja-forms-field.bericht-input');
if( bericht.length ) {
    bericht.attr('required','');
    bericht.attr('data-parsley-trigger','focusout');
    bericht.attr('data-parsley-trigger-after-failure','keyup');
    bericht.attr('minlength','15');
}

//PARSLEY VALIDATION
$('form').parsley();

//field start validation
window.Parsley.on('field:validate', function() {
    var field = this.$element[0].id;
    $('#' + field).parent().find('i').remove(); //remove glyph
});
//field error
window.Parsley.on('field:error', function() {
    var field = this.$element[0].id;
    // This global callback will be called for any field that fails validation.
    console.log('Validation failed for: ', field);
    $('#' + field).parent().append('<i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-lg fa-fw"></i>');
});
//field success
window.Parsley.on('field:success', function() {
    var field = this.$element[0].id;
    // This global callback will be called for any field that fails validation.
    console.log('Validation succeeded for: ', field);
    $('#' + field).parent().append('<i class="fa fa-check-circle fa-lg fa-fw"></i>');
});

});
```

I hope this will help anyone trying to accomplish the same as me.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the original answer...It would be important to remember that a field may have multiple validators (e.g. required, maxLength, custom, etc).

Using Boris' example is great, but would add a fa-check after each successful validation, which is not ideal if you have multiple validators.

Additionally, it would be necessary to remove the success fa-check if the field is modified and fails validation.

Lastly, for those that use bootstrap's `input-group-addon`, which most commonly use the `<i class="fa fa-some-icon"></i>`, it may be a good idea to add a custom CSS class and use the `find()` method to search by, otherwise, using Boris' example would `.reomve()` the bootstrap `i`.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        'use strict';
        // Add fa-check on success, but first remove if it exists
        window.Parsley.on('field:success', function () {
            var field = this.$element[0].id;
            if ($('#' + field).parent().find('.c-success-parsley').length) {
                $('#' + field).parent().find('.c-success-parsley').remove();
            }
            $('#' + field).parent().append('<i class="c-success-parsley fa fa-check"></i>');
        });
        // Remove fa-check on error
        window.Parsley.on('field:error', function () {
            var field = this.$element[0].id;
            if ($('#' + field).parent().find('.c-success-parsley').length) {
                $('#' + field).parent().find('.c-success-parsley').remove();
            }
        });
    });
```